# How to draw label bigger size?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working with Unity and I try to output some info, in order to do this I draw label

```
    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 300, 100), FpsDecoded.ToString("D3")+" FPS Decoded" + (buffereing?" Bufferring...":""));
    }.
```

As a result I see label with output info, but problem is that size of this label very small...

and whatever I do, nothing work. I tried to apply different `Rect` sizes , but text size doesn't changes

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Text size? or label size? text size is defined by a GUIStyle https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved it this way

```
    private GUIStyle guiStyle = new GUIStyle(); //create a new variable

    void OnGUI()
    {
        guiStyle.fontSize = 20;
        string text = FpsDecoded.ToString("D3") + " FPS Decoded" + (buffereing ? " Bufferring..." : "");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 300, 100), text, guiStyle);
    }
```